# Blender, PNG renders and Davinci Ressolve. How to extract data?

Tags: rendering, file-format, render-passes

I am confused on how to render a mist pass from Blender that I can use in DaVinci Ressolve.
Everything I find is ussing that mist data to be comped within Blender.

I know I can use OpenEXR file format to export the data I want to use, but due to disk size limitations I have to work with PNGs only.
Is it there a way?

Comment: EXR can save smaller files than PNG if you get the right compression alorithm (i think dwaa does the best if i'm not wrong) Otherwise you can use the file output node in the compositor to do things like saving different passes in different files and formats, but again: EXR should be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here some possible settings for a small sized, yet high quality .EXR export. You don't need to use .PNGs, when exporting images or image sequences, EXR is always better.

[image]

Also, when already in DaVinci Resolve you will have to fix the colours, so that you have them the same as in blender. If you're using AGX, this is a good LUT to Rec709, here, thank me later.

https://we.tl/t-dFWKmovLpu

Comment: Thank you, but these compression settings reduces file size by sacrifycing image quality (DWAA (lossy) means lose of quality, as it does Float (Half) instead of Full)

I guess we can not have it all and even with these settings I will still get an acceptable quality. 
Thank you!

Comment: @Sumatra Yes, you're right, these compression settings are indeed not lossless, however, please keep in mind that there is no loss of quality noticeable by eye with these settings. The amount of data loss depends on the compression level. The default compression level yields a perceptibly lossless image but a drastic reduction in file size. I have been using them for 4K exports and exactly for my workflow with DaVinci Resolve. This is the best you get, smaller than PNGs and retain quality! It's amazing in my view.